# Upstart script runs well with sudo but fails as root user

Tags: upstart, init.d

I have a simple nodeJs upstart service run as,

```
script
  exec /usr/bin/node /path/to/server.js
end script
```

On running with sudo command, it works

```
~$ sudo service upserv start
sg_gui_server start/running, process 19321
```

When it is ran as a root user, it fails with bizarre error.

```
~$ sudo su
sk# service sg_gui_server restart
karaf: JAVA_HOME not set; results may vary
```

JAVA_HOME not set, this error is bizarre as nodeJs is not dependent on java libs and this error comes, when i run a simple python server as well.

How does running a service with sudo prefix differ from running it as a root user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your configuration, but it appears that your local environment variable for JAVA_HOME is being used *from your user*. You can verify this by checking for the env_keep settings in /etc/sudoers.

I would personally `source /etc/profile` as part of your upstart script.